# Calculus fence and corral

Tags: calculus

Two straight fences meet at a point, but not necessarily at right angel between them. A post stand in the angle between them. If a triangular corral is constructed by building a new straight fence containing this post, show that the fenced off triangle has minimal area when the old post is in the center of the new fence. 
I draw the triangle, labeled first two fence as x and y and angle between them as $t$ then 3th fence divided two pieces and labeled $a$ and $b$. 
$\frac{xysin{t}}{2}=AREA_{min}$
All coming my mind is cos theorem but it get rids of a and b while i need at least one of them. (Sorry i dont know how to draw triangle.)

Comment: @DougM sorry i miss ; A post stand in the angle between them.

Comment: @DougM : There is an isolated post standing in the sector bounded by the two fences.

Comment: This is a retelling of the story in [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2725059/calculus-road-constructing)  The only difference is you are not given a right angle between the first two fences.  Do you recognize it?  Why did you repost it?

Comment: @RossMillikan i recognized it after posting but it still give me something else.

Comment: You can do an affine transformation to turn this problem into the previous one.  Affine transformations preserve the ratios of areas, so will preserve the solution here.  You may not have studied these.

Comment: @RossMillikan i solved the problem but i didnt get idea of question how a and b effecting area of triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Put the post at the origin and the intersection of the two fence segments on the circle of constant distance from the post.  Then the $x$-axis contains the third fence section.  Labelling the two parts of the third fence $a$ and $b$ as you did, we have a triangle with base $a+b$ and height $r \cdot \sin \theta$.  Now maximize area with respect to varying $\theta$.  Once you have the optimal $\theta$, show that this makes $a = b$.

[image: Mathematica graphics]